# Customize SharePoint 2010 WebPart ToolPart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

im trying to Customize a SharePoint 2010 WebPart ToolPart following this tutorial

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dudin/archive/2011/04/17/sharepoint-2010-how-to-customize-the-web-part-tool-part.aspx

Please can anyone confirm if its working because im getting :

*"The operation could not be completed because the Web Part was deleted by another user or is invalid."*

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done ;)

to get the value of DropDownListValue i use :

```
((VisualWebPart1)this.Parent).DropDownListValue;
```